# Polyglot ubuntu not able to download language files

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, polyglot

I have installed polyglot in ubuntu system using

```
sudo apt-get install polyglot
```

also installed dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -y libicu-dev python3-pip
```

when i run polyglot command in console

```
polyglot polyglot.ini download LANG:en
```

gives me following error

```
tellusererror POLYGLOT: pipex_open(): execvp(): /home/userxxx/Projects/nlp_server/nlpserver: Permission denied
```

nlpserver folder have permission as 777

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
```

used this command to install polyglot and it started working.

```
https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html
```